# How to write $3\times 7\times 11\times \ldots \times (4n-1)$ as a factorial?

Tags: factorial

A certain pattern is $3\times 7\times 11\times \ldots \times(4n-1)$.
How could this pattern be written as a factorial? There doesn't seem to be a way to factor out some number but is there a possible way to add one to each number?

I understand that patterns such as $2\times 4\times 6\times \ldots \times (2n)$ can be written like $2^n \times n!$. Is this also possible for this pattern? 
I can't seem to find a way to write it.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I don't believe its a duplicate- my factorial cannot be found by dividing out other factorials.

Comment: You’re right; I had misread. Apologies.

Comment: Since the product of the first $n$ numbers congruent to $3$ mod $4$ will include, on occasion, a large prime congruent to $3$ mod $4$ but never any large primes congruent to $1$ mod $4$, it's hard to see how it could be written as a simple expression with factorials and powers of $n$.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A008545

Comment: i think the answer is no. But is fun to write this: $$\prod_{i=1}^{n} (4n-1)=f(n)n!\\\Rightarrow \dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^{n} (4n-1)}{n!}=f(n)$$

Comment: Please choose a careful formulation of he question. As it stands the answer is a plain no: for instance $21$ _is_ not a factorial, and since it ain't, you cannot (validly) _write_ it as a factorial either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of *pure* factorials, I do not think that this is possible.

However, if you remember that $\Gamma(x+1)=x!$, you can write
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} (4i-1)=4^n \,\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}=4^n \,\frac{\left(n-\frac{1}{4}\right)!}{\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)!}$$