# Expressing the coefficients of $(1-x)^{1/4}$ using factorials

Tags: binomial-coefficients, factorial, closed-form, gamma-function

From the fact that $1\times3\times5\times\ldots\times(2n-1)=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$, we can show that
$$
(1-x)^{1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!n!2^{2n+1}}x^n.
$$
However, can I do the same thing for $(1-x)^{1/4}$? I need to find a closed form of $3\times 7\times11\times\ldots\times(4n-1)$ in terms of factorial, similar to the identity above. I tried wolfram, but it only gives it in terms of gamma function without proof.

How can I express the product 
$$
\prod_{r=0}^n ({ar+d})
$$
in a closed form of factorial or gamma function?

Comment: See here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Generalizations

Comment: The specific case can be found here [How to write $3\times 7\times 11\times \ldots \times (4n-1)$ as a factorial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2479353)

Answer (score 1):

$$P_n=\prod_{r=0}^n ({ar+d})=d a^n \left(\frac{a+d}{a}\right)_n$$ using Pochhammmer symbols.

In terms of the gamma function  $$P_n=a^{n+1}\frac{\Gamma \left(n+1+\frac{d}{a}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{d}{a}\right)}$$